# When I click delete button it's just refreshing but not deleting

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I click delete button in popup modal it's just refreshing but not deleting, I think it's bad URL, what can I do? I added all my  code, Please help me

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="<?php echo $darb_id ?>">
     <?php
    echo "<td><a rel={$darb_id} href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-danger delete_link'>Ištrinti</a></td>";?>

    </form>
```

MY DELETE MODAL CODE:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">DELETE message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 class="text-center"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger modal_delete_link">DELETE</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".delete_link").on('click', function(){

          var id = $(this).attr("rel");

          var delete_url = "darb.php?delete="+ id;

          $(".modal_delete_link").attr("href", delete_url);

          $("#myModal").modal('show');

      });
  });
```

My darb.php code where everything happens

```
<?php

include("delete_modal.php");
include("look_darb.php");


    $query = "SELECT * FROM darb ORDER BY darb_id DESC ";
    $select_darb = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_darb)) {
        $darb_id            = $row['darb_id'];
        $darb_user          = $row['darb_user'];
        $darb_title         = $row['darb_title'];
        $darb_status        = $row['darb_status'];
        $darb_date          = $row['darb_date'];
        $darb_work          = $row['darb_work'];
        $darb_finish        = $row['darb_finish'];
        $darb_result        = $row['darb_result'];
        $darb_fileUpload    = $row['darb_fileUpload'];
        $darb_payment       = $row['darb_payment'];

        echo "<tr>"; ?>

 <td><input class='checkBoxes' type='checkbox' name='checkBoxArray[]' value='<?php echo $darb_id; ?>'></td>

        <?php

        echo "<td>$darb_id </td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_user</td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_title</td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_status</td>";
        echo "<td>$darb_date</td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_result</td>";

        echo "<td><a href='../uploads/$darb_fileUpload'>$darb_fileUpload</a></td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_payment</td>";
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="darb_id" value="<?php echo $darb_id ?>">
         <?php
          echo "<td><a rel={$darb_id} href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-primary look_link'>Peržiūrėti</a></td>";?>
        </form>
        <?php

        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-info' href='darb.php?source=edit_darb&d_id={$darb_id}'>Redaguoti</a></td>";?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="<?php echo $darb_id ?>">
         <?php
        echo "<td><a rel={$darb_id} href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-danger delete_link'>Ištrinti</a></td>";?>

        </form>
        <?php
    }

      ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $the_darb_id = escape($_POST['darb_id']);

    $query = "DELETE FROM darb WHERE darb_id = {$the_darb_id} ";
    $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    header("Location: /pvd/admin/darb.php");
}



?>
```

I have tried a lot of advice online but couldn't resolve this problem.

Comment: Where are you deleting data from? DB, filesystem, other?

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you even attempt to delete anything

Comment: I deleting info from DB

Comment: I'm using this code in other projects and it's working fine, but in this project doesn't

Comment: This code would not delete anything. There is no DB interaction here.

Comment: Strange, I did this in other project and this code working fine. Okey, I can try interacting with DB

Comment: i your javascript code after var `delete_url` just add `console(delete_url)` and check what it shows. Hope you know how to get console data.

Comment: @AmitRay, Now I see the problem, Thank you. Problem 
 Uncaught TypeError: console is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (darb.php?id=77:351)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)

Comment: sorry you have to mention `console.log(delete_url);`.

Comment: @AmitRay It's redirecting me to darb.php page with id. darb.php?id=77
Navigated to http://localhost/pvd/admin/darb.php?id=77

Comment: That means it is able to get the id. But without checking complete script we cannot guess. Can you upload darb.php script here.

Comment: @AmitRay I added darb.php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full code solved:**

```
    <?php

include("delete_modal.php");
include("look_darb.php");


    $query = "SELECT * FROM darb ORDER BY darb_id DESC ";
    $select_darb = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_darb)) {
        $darb_id            = $row['darb_id'];
        $darb_user          = $row['darb_user'];
        $darb_title         = $row['darb_title'];
        $darb_status        = $row['darb_status'];
        $darb_date          = $row['darb_date'];
        $darb_work          = $row['darb_work'];
        $darb_finish        = $row['darb_finish'];
        $darb_result        = $row['darb_result'];
        $darb_fileUpload    = $row['darb_fileUpload'];
        $darb_payment       = $row['darb_payment'];

        echo "<tr>"; ?>

 <td><input class='checkBoxes' type='checkbox' name='checkBoxArray[]' value='<?php echo $darb_id; ?>'></td>

        <?php

        echo "<td>$darb_id </td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_user</td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_title</td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_status</td>";
        echo "<td>$darb_date</td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_result</td>";

        echo "<td><a href='../uploads/$darb_fileUpload'>$darb_fileUpload</a></td>";

        echo "<td>$darb_payment</td>";
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="darb_id" value="<?php echo $darb_id ?>">
         <?php
          echo "<td><a rel={$darb_id} href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-primary look_link'>Peržiūrėti</a></td>";?>
        </form>
        <?php

        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-info' href='darb.php?source=edit_darb&d_id={$darb_id}'>Redaguoti</a></td>";?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="<?php echo $darb_id ?>">
         <?php
        echo "<td><a rel={$darb_id} href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-danger delete_link'>Ištrinti</a></td>";?>

        </form>
        <?php
    }

      ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $the_darb_id = escape($_POST['delete']);

    $query = "DELETE FROM darb WHERE darb_id = {$the_darb_id} ";
    $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    header("Location: /pvd/admin/darb.php");
}



?>
```

**Explanation of the solution:**

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
//assign the variable  $the_darb_id to $_POST['delete'
    $the_darb_id = escape($_POST['delete']);
```

Comment: Please explain what changes you made. So that the OP can understand.

Comment: Done explained now.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$the_darb_id = escape($_POST['darb_id']);
```

to this:

```
$the_darb_id = escape($_POST['delete']);
```

Because there's no `$_POST['darb_id']`.

P.S. You also might want to `DELETE` before you `SELECT`.